# 'weighed in' vs 'wade in'

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

When someone to gives their opinion on a complex topic, is the phrase used "weighed in" or "wade in"? I thought it was the former, but I've been seeing the latter crop up more and more often.

Examples:

1a. Jack and Jill were having a fight and Mark weighed in on the matter to settle the dispute.

1b. Jack and Jill were having a fight and Mark wade in on the matter to settle the dispute.

2a. Mary and Jane were having a fight and asked Mark to weigh in on the matter.

2b. Mary and Jane were having a fight and asked Mark to wade in on the matter.

Comment: It's *weigh/weighed*--Mark lends his 'weight' to the matter. But people who know the use only in speech and have never read it may be unaware of the background metaphor; it's reasonable for them to assume that this is a use of *wade*, as in *wade into a fight*.

Comment: You do often hear people say "Mark waded in".  The metaphor being to go in deeply.

Comment: "wade in" - a side effect of the text message epidemic.

Comment: How could it be _wade in_ in 1b? The sentence is obviously in the past tense, but _wade_ is present tense. If _wade_ were the correct verb, it would have to be _waded_ in. Have you ever heard anyone say that?

Comment: @Oldbag: Brought to you by the makers of "visit my web sight".

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. However, there's evidence that the two idioms are merging: Google shows almost 300 actual uses of *waded in on* and *has waded in on*, many from professionally written sources like the Daily Telegraph and Daily Mirror.

Comment: Both are used in different contexts.  Since they mean entirely different things, it would be unwise to interchange them.

Comment: 'wade in' is an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) for 'weighed in' (the latter is the original)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the correct expression for contributing to a discussion, debate, or what have you, would be `to weigh in on` (or `to weigh in with`). This informal phrase has a few variant meanings, such as:

> to join in a discussion, an argument, an activity, etc. by saying something important, persuading someone, or doing something to help

[*Oxford Advanced American Dictionary*]

> to offer an opinion, advice, support, etc., especially in a forceful or authoritative way

[*Dictionary.com*]

> to bring in one's weight, metaphorically speaking, to bear on an issue

[*Wiktionary*]

In your examples, it appears that Mark is being called upon to lend his influence to an ongoing exchange. Therefore, *weighing in* seems the most apt description of what he's being asked to do.

---

However, I don't think that `to wade into` is technically incorrect, depending on your interpretation of the text. The use of that phrase usually denotes a sense of undertaking a difficult—if not downright impossible—task.

So, if we're looking at your examples from Mark's point of view, and perhaps from further context we understood that any conflict between Jack and Jill (or Mary and Jane) can become a lengthy and convoluted battle, it could be said that he's *wading into* a situation in which he might be mired for some time.

That being said, I do believe that `wade in on` is an unusual construction, although I don't know that it's actually wrong. If it were me, I would definitely switch out *on* for *to* when using *wade*.

Answer (score -1):

An old (1999) edition of the Concise Oxford Dictionary gives both.
Wade in/into (informal): attack, intervene, or become involved in a vigorous or forceful way.
Weigh in (informal): make a forceful contribution to a competition or argument.
Weigh into: join in or attack forcefully or enthusiastically.

Comment: 'weigh in' is forceful? I disagree with that. It seems less forceful.